# Java Garbage Collection Tuning - -XX:GCTimeLimit and -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit not working?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

In our GC logs, we are seeing this sort of pattern for extended periods of time (20+ minutes).  Here is small snapshot of the Full GCs running during this time:

```
2017-08-17T17:40:55.958-0500: 2263.468: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698843K->698835K(698880K)] 899035K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3358980 secs] [Times: user=12.79 sys=0.03, real=0.33 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:56.294-0500: 2263.805: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698835K->698835K(698880K)] 899027K->899027K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.4146470 secs] [Times: user=14.99 sys=0.04, real=0.42 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:56.710-0500: 2264.220: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698835K->698835K(698880K)] 899027K->899027K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3549330 secs] [Times: user=14.16 sys=0.03, real=0.35 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:57.065-0500: 2264.576: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200191K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698835K->698835K(698880K)] 899027K->899027K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3333880 secs] [Times: user=12.86 sys=0.04, real=0.34 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:57.399-0500: 2264.910: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200191K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698843K->698835K(698880K)] 899035K->899027K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3361300 secs] [Times: user=13.10 sys=0.04, real=0.33 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:57.736-0500: 2265.246: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200191K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698845K->698835K(698880K)] 899037K->899027K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3165070 secs] [Times: user=11.66 sys=0.03, real=0.32 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:58.053-0500: 2265.564: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200191K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698835K->698834K(698880K)] 899027K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3860970 secs] [Times: user=15.29 sys=0.09, real=0.39 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:58.440-0500: 2265.951: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698834K->698834K(698880K)] 899026K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3679940 secs] [Times: user=14.06 sys=0.04, real=0.37 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:58.809-0500: 2266.319: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698834K->698834K(698880K)] 899026K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3336190 secs] [Times: user=12.92 sys=0.03, real=0.33 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:59.143-0500: 2266.654: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698834K->698834K(698880K)] 899026K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3498820 secs] [Times: user=13.31 sys=0.04, real=0.35 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:59.494-0500: 2267.004: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698834K->698834K(698880K)] 899026K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3055050 secs] [Times: user=11.00 sys=0.04, real=0.31 secs] 
2017-08-17T17:40:59.800-0500: 2267.310: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 200192K->200191K(272896K)] [ParOldGen: 698834K->698834K(698880K)] 899026K->899026K(971776K) [PSPermGen: 26732K->26732K(26880K)], 0.3235970 secs] [Times: user=12.22 sys=0.05, real=0.32 secs]
```

So we have Full GC running multiple times per second, leaving very little time for this JVM to do any real work.  We tried setting the following arguments to force a "GC overhead" OOM when this occurs:

```
-XX:GCTimeLimit=5    
-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=50
```

Here is the Oracle documentation on these for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

I would think with these settings in place (>5% of time spent in GC, <50% heap free), we would be triggering a OutOfMemoryError: GC Overhead limit exceeded.  Any thoughts on why this is NOT triggering like we expect?

Edit - a little more info, here is the top of the GC log, showing version info, arguments, etc:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.101-b14) for linux-x86 JRE (1.7.0_101-b14), built on Mar 31 2016 05:26:20 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)
Memory: 4k page, physical 131954348k(1343412k free), swap 125812704k(125512524k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=50 -XX:GCTimeLimit=5 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/cerner/core_files -XX:InitialHeapSize=446693376 -XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/local/cwx/ejs_oom.ksh -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have disabled it with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

> Edit - a little more info, here is the top of the GC log, showing version info, arguments, etc:
>   `-XX:GCTimeLimit=0`

That's clearly not the option you say you have set.

Comment: Here are my command line flags, based on the GC log:


`-XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=50 -XX:GCTimeLimit=0 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/cerner/core_files -XX:InitialHeapSize=446693376 -XX:MaxHeapSize=1073741824 -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/local/cwx/ejs_oom.ksh -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+UseParallelGC`

Comment: Oops, I grabbed the wrong set of arguments (I was trying everything I could think, but same results when GCTimeLimit was set to 0 vs. 5).  I updated the original post to clarify this, thanks!